# How to get Eclipse to resolve BuildInfo in an sbt / Scala/ BuildInfo project

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

Some Scala / SBT projects such as [Tugboat](https://github.com/softprops/tugboat) or [giter8](https://github.com/n8han/giter8) use [BuildInfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) - for example see [here](https://github.com/softprops/tugboat/blob/master/src/main/scala/Client.scala#L50) and [here](https://github.com/n8han/giter8/blob/0.6.7/app/src/main/scala/giter8.scala#L37). When I import these projects into Eclipse after creating project files using [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) the project will not compile as it cannot resolve BuildInfo.

There are some instructions about how to resolve this [in the BuildInfo README](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo#eclipse-support). However If I add the suggested line to the Tugboat [SBT file](https://github.com/softprops/tugboat/blob/master/build.sbt):

```
  EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Managed
```

it does not resolve the problem. In the Tugboat [SBT file](https://github.com/softprops/tugboat/blob/master/build.sbt#L21) it specifies some other settings - do I need to do anything else to get access to BuildInfo in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The `EclipseCreateSrc.Managed` setting tells Eclipse to use *managed sources* i.e. automatically created code. In the case of tugboat, the BuildInfo managed source should be found in `tugboat\target\scala-2.11\src_managed\main\sbt-buildinfo` (the exact directory depends on your Scala version).

I resolved my problem by calling `compile` from the sbt command line prior to building in Eclipse. This should generate the BuildInfo.scala file. Once this is file is present the project should generate successfully. Eclipse does not seem to be able to generate this file itself.